# Formatted text displays outside of floating container

Tags: html, css

I created a container. Plain text in the container displays inside the container, however, formatted text displays outside of the container. Please give suggestions. My html and css are posted below.

This is my html:

```css
.left-column {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.right-column {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
#container {
  width: 900px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1.5px solid #FFCC99;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.border1 {
  width: 910px;
  border: 3px solid #376092;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 2px;
}
border2 {
  width: 915px;
  border: 2px solid #FFCC99;
  margin: 12px auto 12px auto;
}
```

```html
<main id="gap">
  <div class="border2">
    <div class="border1">
      <div id="container">
        <div class="left-column">
        </div>
        <div class="right-column">

        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- End Container -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Border1 -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Border2 -->
</main>
```

Comment: So is your question, how do I get formatted text inside the container?

Comment: Is the "formatted text" rendered inside of the div's with the class values of "left-column" and "right-column" or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes Adam, that is my question.

Comment: I figured it out finally! Thank you all for your help : )

Answer (score 2):

because you are `float`ing the `.left-column` and `.right-column`, you should use a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Also I would advise you to use `box-sizing:border-box`,  see more about [border box model](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Here is a snippet:

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left-column {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.right-column {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  /*padding-left: 200px; - this can be removed */
}
#container {
  width: 900px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1.5px solid #FFCC99;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.border1 {
  width: 910px;
  border: 3px solid #376092;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.border2 {
  width: 915px;
  border: 2px solid #FFCC99;
  margin: 12px auto 12px auto;
}
```

```html
<main id="gap">
  <div class="border2">
    <div class="border1">
      <div id="container" class="cf">
        <div class="left-column">text left</div>
        <div class="right-column">text right</div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Container -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Border1 -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Border2 -->
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `overflow:hidden` in `#container`. This will force the container to respect the height of all elements within it, regardless of floating elements.

**CSS**

```
#container {
      width:900px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border:1.5px solid #FFCC99;
      margin: 0;
      padding:10px;
      overflow: hidden; /* Set this rule */
    }
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/9wmbvf0v/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your padding on your #container.

Your css is :
padding: 10px and width: 910px

So, your padding add 20px (10px right, 10px left).

In the end, your #containter width is 920px and your parent div is 910px.

To fix your problem, you need to set the width of your parent to 920 or change the padding to : padding:5px;